# JQuery DataTables Columns Initializing automatically with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, data-binding, datatables

I have a JQuery DataTable and I have been using it for a while, I guess I am missing something here.

However I came into one of the requirement recently to directly bind with JSON Data.

My JSON for example looks like i.e. coming from API :

```
[{"componentNumber":"ABC","factory":"India","productNumber":"CR","productRevisionState":"123","placementTimeLocal":"2018-08-21T00:00:00","position":"up"},{"componentNumber":"ABC","factory":"India","productNumber":"CR","productRevisionState":"123","placementTimeLocal":"2018-08-21T00:00:00","position":"up"},
{"componentNumber":"ABC","factory":"India","productNumber":"CR","productRevisionState":"123","placementTimeLocal":"2018-08-21T00:00:00","position":"up"}]
```

I know that I can use JSON and take columns out in Jquery and pass it to the Datatables columns but what I am looking if there is a simple way where Datatable takes column automatically something like:

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "http://localhost:5555/myapi",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //datasource = data;
                    $('#myTable').DataTable({
                        "Data": JSON.parse(data),
                        "Columns" : JSON.parse(data)
                            });

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            })
```

What I am looking is that:

1. Does JQuery have any such features or not? If not can you suggest
   any other Datatable library which is fast for large dataset.
2. I want to get rid of all extra looping around the code
3. I can't update source system from where data is getting returned

**Updated Version of Code, took from below answers, thanks Kiran for making me move a bit:**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "http://localhost:5555/myapi",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             // **how to get rid of this loop? for looping columns**
                var adColumns = [];
                $.each(data[0], function (i, item) {
                    var col = {
                        data: i,
                        title: i
                    };
                    adColumns.push(col);

        })


                //datasource = data;
                console.log(data);
                $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "data": data,
                    "info": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "columns": adColumns
                });

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        })
```

Comment: please refer this link https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax
and double check your json data as it was or what. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code. It may help you to achieve the desired result. This may not be an optimized code.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

At least one loop will be required to create the array of column names.So you can also use the following code to eliminate multiple loops.

```
var adColumns = [];
  Object.keys(strData[0]).forEach(key => {
    var col = {
      data: key,
      title: key
    };

    adColumns.push(col);
  });
```

```js
$(function() {

    var strData = [{
            "componentNumber": "ABC",
            "factory": "India",
            "productNumber": "CR",
            "productRevisionState": "123",
            "placementTimeLocal": "2018-08-21T00:00:00",
            "position": "up"
        }, {
            "componentNumber": "ABC",
            "factory": "India",
            "productNumber": "CR",
            "productRevisionState": "123",
            "placementTimeLocal": "2018-08-21T00:00:00",
            "position": "up"
        },
        {
            "componentNumber": "ABC",
            "factory": "India",
            "productNumber": "CR",
            "productRevisionState": "123",
            "placementTimeLocal": "2018-08-21T00:00:00",
            "position": "up"
        }
    ];


    /*var dta = strData;

    var tableColumnNames = [];
    var keys = [];

    for (var i in strData) {
        var key = i;
        var val = strData[i];
        for (var j in val) {
            var sub_key = j;

            keys.push(sub_key);

        }
    }

    var sColumns = Array.from(new Set(keys));


    var adColumns = [];
    for (var col in sColumns) {

        var sKey = sColumns[col];

        var col = {
            data: sKey,
            title: sKey
        };

        adColumns.push(col);


    }*/

    var adColumns = [];
    Object.keys(strData[0]).forEach(key => {
        var col = {
            data: key,
            title: key
        };

        adColumns.push(col);
    });


    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "data": strData,
        "columns": JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(adColumns))
    });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Your code works well, however I was looking to get rid of loops! I have updated my question, its working with 1 loop, still if anyway I can get rid of all these loop, will be awesome

Comment: in my view at least one loop will be necessary.

Comment: I will accept your answer with 1 Loop, however its pity that Datatable doesn't get columns automatically. Do you have any other Datatables which are fast and get things done quickly?

Comment: @NipunAmbastha There is another plugin called jqgrid but i'm not famlier with that.check that also.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables has the ability to read data from virtually any JSON data source that can be obtained by Ajax. This can be done, in its most simple form, by setting the `ajax` option to the address of the JSON data source. See  [This Link in DataTable Website](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax).

As for your JSON, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubvsrht1/1/)

Comment: My columns can change anytime, so I don't want to define them explicitly. As you have called Ajax, can Datatable directly take column name as JSON as Key and Value pair and bind, without specifying it anywhere neither on HTML or JQUERY